# Can you configure a specific interface to reach the NTP server?

Tags: centos, linux-networking, ntpd, ntpdate

I have to configure NTP on a CentOS server. I have 7 interfaces and I can reach the NTP server through one interface. Also the server doesn't have access to internet. 
When I try ping:

```
ping 10.0.10.12
connect: Network is unreachable
```

But when I ping with source interface, the ping is successful.

```
ping -I eth0 10.0.10.12
PING 10.0.0.131 (10.0.10.12) from 10.69.4.16 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.10.12: icmp_seq=1 ttl=127 time=4.07 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.10.12: icmp_seq=2 ttl=127 time=0.309 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.10.12: icmp_seq=3 ttl=127 time=0.318 ms
```

ntpstat command output:

```
unsynchronised
 time server re-starting
  polling server every 8s
```

ntpq -p command output:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 10.0.10.12      .INIT.          16 -    -  512    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

I also tried ntpdate - d 10.0.10.12:

```
ntpdate -d 10.0.0.131
23 Jul 09:14:31 ntpdate[16715]: ntpdate 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Sat Nov 23 18:21:48 UTC 2013 (1)
Looking for host 10.0.0.131 and service ntp
host found : 10.0.0.131
23 Jul 09:14:31 ntpdate[16715]: no servers can be used, exiting
```

The NTP server is configured in the ntp.conf file, I think that the problem is something with the network. I was wondering if I can make explicit source interface for reaching the NTP server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved this concluding that NTP requires default gateway for working properly. This was solution for me:

```
ip route add default via 127.0.0.1 dev lo
```

Comment: A default route via localhost? I'd assume this complicates things further, but YMMV...

Answer (score 3):

<strike>You can add a specific host route for your NTP server:</strike>

`route add -host 10.0.10.12 dev eth0`, for example.

As per Anton's completely correct comment, here is the command in `iproute2` syntax:

`ip route add 10.0.10.12 dev eth0`

Comment: Stop using of the deprecated commands!

Comment: Force of habit. I added the new command.

Comment: This is in the eth0 table: ip route show table eth0table,
10.69.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link,
default via 10.69.4.1 dev eth0.

Comment: @ananetworking unfortunately, the server `10.0.10.12` isn't in `10.69.0.0/16`, so that route won't help.  I should try Lenniey's answer before complaining about it!